# .env file always returning None using os.environ.get() and os.environ[]

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

I'm trying to access the .env file but it always returns None, here is my file structure:

[image]

In my .env file, I've written:

```
BOT_TOKEN=someHiddenText
CLIENT_ID=anotherHiddenText
CLIENT_SECRET=anotherHiddenText
```

I've tried doing:

```
print(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN'))
print(os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'])
```

And both of these methods return None, so what am I doing wrong here? Any reply will be appreciated! Here is also the error message just in case it's useful.

```
(environment) PS C:\Users\Steven Kristian\Documents\Portfolio\Tohru> heroku local worker
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
11:48:10 worker.1   |  None
11:48:10 worker.1   |  None
11:48:10 worker.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
11:48:10 worker.1   |    File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
11:48:10 worker.1   |      TOKEN = os.environ['BOT_TOKEN']
11:48:10 worker.1   |    File "C:\Users\Steven Kristian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
11:48:10 worker.1   |      raise KeyError(key) from None
11:48:10 worker.1   |  KeyError: 'BOT_TOKEN'
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
11:48:10 worker.1   Exited with exit code null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

os.environ can only get variables that are defined on your host (like HOME, USER, etc) and not from a file. You either set/export them before you run your script:

```
BOT_TOKEN="asdfghjkl" python script.py

export BOT_TOKEN="asdfghjkl"; python script.py
```

or use a python library like python-dotenv to get env config for your project:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

then you can load your .env vars by doing

```py
from dotenv import dotenv_values

config = dotenv_values(".env")
print(config["BOT_TOKEN"])
```

Comment: Do you have chinese/japanese/etc characters in your .env file? You can try to pass in an encoding argument: `config = dotenv_values(".env", encoding="utf8")`

Comment: I think there was a mistake on my part, I suspect the .env file contains an invisible character. Because once i remade the .env file it worked fine. Thanks!